# Javascript/jQuery Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of jQuery that animates in some text then animates it out. The parameters of the animation are passed via PHP. I need the animation to loop but only after the animation is complete, but can't quite work it out.

```
<?php if ($text1_1 != "") { ?>

  setTimeout(one_1,0);                              // From 0 to duration
  setTimeout(one_2,<?php echo $duration * 2 ?>);    
  // From duration x2 to duration x3

<?php } ?> 
    

<?php if ($text2_1 != "") { ?> 

 setTimeout(two_1,<?php echo $duration * 3 ?>);     // From duration x3 to duration x4
 setTimeout(two_2,<?php echo $duration * 5 ?>);     // From duration x5 to duration x6

<?php } ?> 

<?php if ($text1_1 != "") { ?> 

  function one_1() {
      $('.text-1_1').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_1 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_1_end ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');
      $('.text-1_2').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_2 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_2_end ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');
      $('.text-1_3').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_3 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_3_end ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');
      $('.text-1_4').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_4 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_4_end ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');
      $('.text-1_5').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_5 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_5_end ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');
  }

  function one_2() {
      $('.text-1_1').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_1 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_1_start ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');
      $('.text-1_2').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_2 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_2_start ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');
      $('.text-1_3').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_3 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_3_start ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');
      $('.text-1_4').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_4 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_4_start ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');
      $('.text-1_5').animate({ <?php echo $animate1_5 ?>: '<?php echo $text1_5_start ?>' }, <?php echo $duration ?>, 'easeInOutCubic');    
  }

<?php } ?>
```

How would you get function one_1() & function one_2() to loop after they've finished animating. There is also the possibility that there will be more similar functions.

Very sorry if this is a bit vague! having a bit of trouble explaining it.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: do both have to be completed before next series starts? or just restart fun1 when it has been completed regardless of func2?

Comment: Thanks for all replies, I think the best thing I would need it to do is completely finish all the animations in function1 and then move on to function2 then move on to function3 etc etc.
And then to loop over again. I need each function to run independently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animate finish callback as described here:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$(element).animate( { animation params }, duration, function(){
    // this is the animation finish callback
});
```

My suggestion is to use a recursive function, put the animation inside and call it recursively  when the animation is finished

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this as a template. If the durations within each group are not the same, will require considerably more logic to set up and you would likely be best to provide all the animation data as an array, not echo to each animation

```
function one_1() {  

    /* use complete callback of  one animation to call next function*/
    $('.text-1_5').animate({ /* anim*/}, /*duration*/, /* easing*/, function(){
       /* this animation is complete, call next function */
        two_1();                                                                                 
    });

    /* other animations for this group*/

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the solution is to replace `setTimeout` with

```
setInterval(two_1,<?php echo $duration; ?>);
setInterval(two_2,<?php echo $duration; ?>);
```

There is now need for doing `$duration * 3` because your animations will start all in the same time

Comment: Where do you see just one argument at my example? there are 2 arguments.. the function and duration.. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp setInterval has 3 arguments but just 2 of them are required, the third being optional